# Server starting slowly

Tags: performance, glassfish, myeclipse

I am using MyEclipse, and I have a local Glassfish server controlled by the IDE.
When I am at work, having a fast internet connection, the server starts quickly.

However, when I am at home, not having as fast an internet connection, the server starts slowly.

The server is on my local box, why would the internet connection speed matter the server startup time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only thing I can think of is that the server is connecting to the web to access xsd files for xml validation or similar. Have you tried sniffing the connection to see what is being requested, if anything?

Have a look at [Ethereal](http://www.ethereal.com/), it's open source and excellent.

Comment: that makes sense, sounds like that would be the reason, I'll look into the tool...do you know if I can comment out or stop the validation somehow?

Comment: Remember this is only a guess, the real problem might be quite different and Ethereal should rule in or out any network connection issues. If it is xsd, then you can modify the xml files to use a different (local) url.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance that the speed of the machines is what is making the difference in startup time?

Comment: same machine, its my laptop, no difference except for internet speed